# JavaScript comparative operator with string zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

`f` is `true`, and `r` is `"0"`, but the comparison resolves to `true`.  After much head scratching, I expect it is because `r` is a string and not boolean or an integer.  What is the best way to handle this?

https://jsfiddle.net/nboeo0z2/

```
var r=$('input[name="myradio"]:checked').val();
var f = true;
console.log('r',r,'f',f,'test',(!f || r) ? true : false);

<input type="radio" value="1" name="myradio">Yes
<input type="radio" checked="checked" value="0" name="myradio">No
```

Comment: val() is a string. A string is truthy.

Comment: Welcome to JavaScript types! https://charlieharvey.org.uk/page/javascript_the_weird_parts

Comment: @epascarello well, more specifically, a non-zero string is truthy.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  Like the article and will read it.  Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any non-empty string is "truthy".  If you know that the value is supposed to look like a number, you can force that conversion:

```
var r = +$('input[name="myradio"]:checked').val();
```

The unary `+` operator forces the string to be converted to a number, and the number `0` is not "truthy".

If the value is *not* numeric, then the numeric conversion will yield `NaN`, and it's just as `false` as `0`.

Comment: Never heard the term `truthy` before.  Very appropriate!  Thanks

Comment: @user1032531 noted JavaScript author Douglas Crockford started using the terms "truthy" and "falsy" a few years ago, borrowing the terminology from American television political satire program *The Colbert Report*.